# Every other character from string Swift

Tags: swift

How do I return string made of every other character from giving string? Like “house” to “hue” help me I wanna do that.

Comment: You surely tried *something.* Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that it does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41030422/2303865

Answer (score -2):

one not very fancy but working way would be:

```
print(stringFromEveryOtherCharacter("house"))

func stringFromEveryOtherCharacter(_ string: String) -> String {

  var result : String = ""
 
  for (index, char) in string.enumerated() {
      if index % 2 == 0 {
          result = result + String(char)
      }
  }

  return result

}
```

which returns "hue"

Comment: I am getting ‘Cannot call value of non-function type ‘string’

Comment: This is not a complete program. This is just a simple draft. It should run in a Playground.

Comment: If you vote down you should offer an alternative (there are numerous) solution.

Comment: I understand that after his follow up answer